# UDP протокол, client-server

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер, ip, udp

Здравствуйте, я делал чат через сокеты Java, клиент - на Андроиде, сервер - на компе (IntelliJIdea).
Делал через простые сокеты: ServerSocket, Socket.  И чтобы можно было "добраться" запросу от клиента к серверу и наоборот, я использовал туннель ngrok, просто прописав в нем команду `ngrok tcp 1000`, к примеру, а в клиенте соответственно переделал под `ngrok InetAddress` и тд. Все работало.

***Теперь я перешёл на UDP, и делаю тот же чат, но клиент сервера не видит, и ngrok не помогает.*** Как быть, может есть какой-то другой туннель? Ну по локальной сети все отлично через UDP работает, а по-другому - нет. Что сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: посмотрел [доку](https://ngrok.com/docs) - там нет упоминания о udp тунелях.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, и я о том же - ngrok для UDP не работает. Но как тогда организовать связь, к примеру сервер находится у соседа, а я со своего сижу роутера. И я ему должен послать например сообщение какое-то, тот же String. Нужен экземпляр класса InetAddress и порт, но как их найти чтобы именно к нему добраться?

Comment: самый простой способ - сделайте себе нормальный внешний айпи (например, статический) и пробросьте на роутере). Сложный путь - изучить nat tunneling и вперед.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как сделать статический айпи и пробросить на роутере, я просто в этом не совсем шарю?

Comment: Статический айпи - это к вашему провайдеру.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я понимаю, но как его "сделать" и пробросить?

Comment: Сделать - это к провайдеру. Я никак не помогу тут. А пробросить - нужна модель роутера и можно будет нарушить.

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошо, спасибо, буду разбираться дальше

Comment: Можете воспользоваться услугами http://noip.com если вам нужен статический адрес.